# In the function get.hist.quote how can I save the only date?

Tags: r

With

```
library(zoo)
SPY <- get.hist.quote("SPY",
                      start = "2010-01-01",
                      end = "2011-01-01",
                      quote = "AdjClose", 
                      compression = "d",
                      retclass = c("zoo","ts"))
```

I get a matrix with date and associated prices, how can I save the only date? Writing  `coredata(SPY$Adjusted[,1])` does not work.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPY is a timeseries, you can use `time(SPY)` to get the dates